# Count values in multidimensional array and save the result as new array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, count

Here is my multidim. array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [language] => English
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [language] => English
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [language] => English
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [language] => English
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [language] => English
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [language] => English
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [language] => English
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [language] => English
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [language] => English
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [language] => English
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [language] => English
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [language] => English
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [language] => English
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [language] => English
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [language] => English
        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [language] => English
        )

    [16] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [language] => English
        )

    [17] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [language] => English
        )

    [18] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [language] => English
        )

    [19] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [language] => English
        )

    [20] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [language] => English
        )

    [21] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [language] => English
        )

    [22] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [language] => English
        )

    [23] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [language] => English
        )

    [24] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [language] => Italian
        )

    [25] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [language] => German
        )

    [26] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [language] => German
        )

    [27] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [language] => German
        )

    [28] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [language] => German
        )

    [29] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [language] => German
        )

    [30] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [language] => German
        )

    [31] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [language] => German
        )

    [32] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [language] => German
        )

    [33] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [language] => German
        )

    [34] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [language] => German
        )

    [35] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [language] => German
        )

    [36] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [language] => German
        )

)
```

I know how to loop through the array and how to count values but this time I also need to check whether the [id] is in an array with multiple languages and it has to work fully dynamic for different queries.

The new array shall look like this:

```
Array (  
   [1] => Array(
        "English" => 24,
        "German" => 12
   ),
   [2] => Array(
         "Italian" => 1
   )
)
```

Comment: So by "*is in an array with multiple languages*" you mean "*is an array whose length is greater than one*"?

Comment: Pretty much never appropriate to use pastebin. Put everything required to answer your question *in your question*.

Comment: Can you show how you're counting them up currently?

Answer (score 0):

```
$sorted_array = array("English" => 0, "German" => 0);
foreach($old_array as $a) {
   if(isset($a['language']) && strlen($a['language']) >= 1) {
      switch($a['language']) {

         case 'English' :
           $sorted_array['English']++;
         break;
         case 'German' :
           $sorted_array['German']++;
         break;

      }
   }
}
```

Just to get you going...  And if you're real clever you can use array_keys to automatically populate your sorted_array() for you...  (google it)